# Differential Equations proof for Prove that $\dim(\ker(TU)) ≤ (\dim\ker(T)) + \dim(\ker(U))$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $T$ and $U$ be linear transformations $V → V$ with ﬁnite-dimensional kernels.

> Prove that
>
> $\dim(\ker(TU)) ≤ (\dim\ker(T)) + \dim(\ker(U))$

My tutor suggested that I create two new transformations by restricting the range and domain of $U$ and $V$ in the following way $\hat U : V → U(V )$ and $\hat T : U(V ) → V $. Note that the compositions $TU$ and $\hat T \hat U$ are identical, that $\hat U$ is onto, and that $\dim(\ker(\hat T)) ≤ \dim(\ker(T))$

But I still do not understand.

Comment: This section is related to Differential equations where we are finding the basis of the generalized eigenvectors for solving systems of differential equations

Comment: This is a pure *linear algebra* problem. I think you should also add this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the map 
$F: \ker(TU)\to \ker(T)$ that maps each $x\in \ker(TU)$ in $F(x)=Ux$ (you can observe that this map is the restriction of U to $\ker(TU)$. Then you have that 
$$\frac{\ker(TU)}{\ker(F)}=\operatorname{Im}(F),$$
but $\ker(F)=\ker(U)$ and so
\begin{align*}
\dim(\ker(TU))&=\dim\left(\frac{\ker(TU)}{\ker(F)}\right)+\dim(\ker(F))\\
&=\dim(\operatorname{Im}(F))+\dim(\ker(U))\\
&\leq\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\ker(U))\\
\end{align*}
Because $\operatorname{Im}(F)$ is a subspace of $\ker(T)$.